# Slow JQuery CSS Layout Calls on WordPress (Forced Reflow)

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, layout

We currently have a performance issue with a WordPress theme that is running some custom resizing / layout functions. They mainly relate to 'sticky' menus that scroll with the screen, being called when the screen scrolls or the window is resized. Disabling them instantly solves the problem but makes the theme unusable as when you resize or scroll, the menu's are no longer responsive (As expected)

In all, they can take upwards of 3.5s to complete and have a significant UX impact. From Google Chrome, the drill down eventually leads us here:

[image]

**Further Info:**

- The performance issue is only apparent on Google Chrome. No other
  browsers are affected.
- The site had no code changes pushed, performance slowly degraded and
  'janking' became a problem.
- The issue was apparent during development on the server the code
  currently resides on (Server Alpha), the code was moved to another entirely separate
  cluster (Server Beta) and the issue disappeared immediately. Identical code on the
  other server (Server Beta) does not have the same issue in a like for like test at this moment in time.
- The site is hosted on Apache (Server Alpha) with a slightly older version of PHP5.
  Caching is not enabled on resources e.g. CSS
- The calls are MenuResize() and MenuSticky() from the 'hillter' theme.
- The main time is spent in Scripting, not Painting, in the time break downs.

**Possible Causes:**

The following are some best guesses I've had:

- The development hosting site (Server Beta), that does not show the same issue, is far superior from a network and processing power perspective. Its also physically closer to us. Is it possible that the slow calls are pulling CSS over the network from the current hosting server (Server Alpha) each time (As caching is disabled) and the slow time we are seeing is actually the JQuery scripts retrieving the CSS again?

**Code:**

```
/*Menu Sticky*/
function MenuSticky() {

    if($('#header_content').length) {

        var $this = $('#header_content'),
            size_point = $this.data().responsive,
            window_w = window.innerWidth,
            window_scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            top_h = $('#header .header_top').innerHeight(),
            this_h = $this.innerHeight(),
            top_bar = 0;


        if($('body').hasClass('admin-bar')) {
            top_bar = parseInt($('html').css('marginTop').replace('px', ''));
        }

        if(size_point == undefined || size_point == '') {
            size_point = 1199;
        }

        if( window_scroll > (top_h + top_bar) ) {

            if(($this).hasClass('sticky-enable') == true) {

                $this.addClass('header-sticky').css('top', top_bar + 'px');
                // $('#header').append('<div class="fix-sticky" style="height: '+this_h+'px"></div>')
                if(window_w <= size_point) {
                    $this.find('.header_menu').css('top', this_h + top_bar + 'px');
                }
            }

        } else {
            $this.removeClass('header-sticky').css('top', '');
            // $('#header').find('.fix-sticky').remove();
            if(window_w <= size_point) {
                $this.find('.header_menu').css('top', (this_h + top_h + top_bar) + 'px');
            }
        }

        if($this.hasClass('header-sticky')) {
            if(window_w <= 600) {
                $this.css('top', '');
                $this.find('.header_menu').css('top', this_h + 'px');
            } else {
                $this.css('top', top_bar + 'px');
            }
        }
        console.log('test');
    }
}

/* Menu Resize */
function MenuResize() {

    if ($('#header_content').length) {

        var $this = $('#header_content'),
            size_point = $this.data().responsive,
            window_scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            top_h = $('#header .header_top').innerHeight(),
            this_h = $this.innerHeight(),
            window_w = window.innerWidth,
            top_bar = 0;

        if($('body').hasClass('admin-bar')) {
            top_bar = parseInt($('html').css('marginTop').replace('px', ''));
        }

        if (size_point == undefined || size_point == '') {
            size_point = 1199;
        }

        if (window_w <= size_point) {
            $this.addClass('header_mobile').removeClass('header_content');
        } else {
            $('.menu-bars').removeClass('active');
            $this.removeClass('header_mobile').addClass('header_content');
            $('#header_content .header_menu').css({
                'top': ''
            }).removeClass('active').find('ul').css('display', '');
        }

        if($this.hasClass('header-sticky')) {

            $this.css('top', top_bar + 'px');
        } else {
            $this.css('top', '');
        }
    }
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#hillter-preloader').delay(1000).fadeOut('400', function () {
            $(this).fadeOut()
        });
        $('body').append('<div class="awe-popup-overlay" id="awe-popup-overlay"></div><div class="awe-popup-wrap" id="awe-popup-wrap"><div class="awe-popup-content"></div><span class="awe-popup-close" id="awe-popup-close"></div>');
        GalleryIsotope();
        GuestBookMasonry();
        AttractionMap();
        ContactMap();
    });

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        MenuSticky();
    });

    $(window).resize(function (event) {
        ParallaxScroll();
        PopupCenter();
        MenuResize();
        MenuSticky();
        AttractionClick();
    }).trigger('resize');

    // Fix calendar in tab hillter.
    $('.apb-product_tab-header a').on('shown.bs.tab', function() {
        if ( $('#calendar').length ) {
            $('#calendar, #calendar2').fullCalendar('render');
        }
    });

    $('.awe-overlay').each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        if ( el.parents('.vc_row').length != 0 ) {
            el.parents('.vc_row').css({
              'position': 'relative'
            })  ;
            el.css({
              'position': 'absolute'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

We undertook the following steps:

- Minify CSS
- Move CSS off the DOM and into linked files
- Enabled all caching, browser and server side. Improved JQuery as much as
  possible
- Taking janw's suggestion and in addition to factoring out what was not needed

Still slow. *3.8s of scripting time slow.*

The real issue, this:

[image: Code issue]

The site has Spanish content and in one of the transports, it would appear a special character was corrupted, generating this output in the Chrome browser. During JQuery DOM parsing, it hit this block and all hell broke lose. The simple fix, rectify the characters.

Final page load time: Sub 2s.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you're selecting everything on each scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    MenuSticky();
});

function MenuSticky() {

    if($('#header_content').length) { //.....
    if($('body').hasClass('admin-bar')) { //....
```

Every scroll, and resize. You are selecting a bunch of elements again and again. This is heavy on the DOM.
Better do something like.

```
var $body = $('body'),
    $header_content = $('#header_content');

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    MenuSticky();
});

function MenuSticky() {

    if($header_content.length) { //.....
    if($body.hasClass('admin-bar')) { //....
```

There are a bunch more. But this is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks janw. Unfortunately it isn't my code and its not a part of JQuery I'm very familiar with, but I'll refractor it as best I can and see do we see any improvement. Thanks for the pointer! However, would that explain why one server has issues and the other doesn't?

Comment: javascript executed by the browser has nothing to do with a server. But it can explain the browser diffrence.

Comment: Thanks janw. But the same browser (Only Google Chrome) on two different servers, using the same code, acts differently. Perhaps its pure coincidence!